# Laravel group by interval of 10 minutes / one day

Tags: php, laravel-4, group-by

Can somebody give me an advice how to group results in Laravel 4 by an interval of time?

So the idea is that i need to make some statistics, and i need to select the interval - 10 minutes / 30 minutes / 1 hour / 6 hours / 1 day.

My current code doesn't give me the correct results:

```
$stats = DB::table('orders as o')
    ->select(
        DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(o.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %l:%i') as date"),
        DB::raw('COUNT(o.id) as num'),
        DB::raw('SUM(op.amount * op.quantity) as total'),
        DB::raw('TRUNCATE(AVG(op.amount * op.quantity),0) as avg')
    )
    ->leftJoin('order_products as op', 'o.id','=','op.order_id')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(o.created_at) DIV ' . (Input::get('intval',10) * 60) . ''))
    ->where('o.status','=','verified')
    ->orderBy('o.created_at','ASC')
    ->get();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please be more clear on your question, what you want to achieve

Comment: Hi, i want to group MySQL results in Laravel 4 by an interval of time.
The idea is that i have a date range (min and max) and the interval of time thereby I have these buttons (ex: sales by hour, 6 hours and by day). 
So, when i click on the button with interval of one hour then i need to get the COUNT of sales, groupped by hourly.
The other one is, when i click on the button of One Day, i need to get the COUNT of sales groupped by daily. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the code, for better understanding.